# Control javascript hide/show div with radio controls without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

The code below doesn't seem to work

//javascript

```
function t_show() {
    if(document.getElementById("t_show").checked == true){
        if(document.getElementById("t_show").value == 1) {
            showDiv("t_settings");
        }
    } else {
        hideDiv("t_settings");
    }
}

function show(show){
    var s = document.getElementById(show);
    if(!s) return true;
    s.style.display="";
    return true;
}

function hide(hide){
    var h = document.getElementById(hide);
    if(!h) return true;
    h.style.display="none";
    return true;
}
```

//html

```
Text show:
<input type="radio" name="t_show" value="1"  checked="checked" onchange="t_show(); update_preview();" id="t_show">Yes 
<input type="radio" name="t_show" value="0"                    onchange="t_show(); update_preview();" id="t_show">No 

<div id="t_settings">This content is to be shown if the show text is enabled.</div>
```

Comment: if there are multiple divs like this. Also if I wanna hide a table, or a tr, and td along with this, how do i do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You `<div/>` has a class of `t_settings` but you are calling `getElementById()`
2. You are calling `showDiv()` but the function name is actually `show()`
3. You are calling `hideDiv()` but the function name is actually `hide()`
4. Instead of doing `s.style.display = "";` use `s.style.display = "block";`
5. `document.getElementById("t_show").value == 1` will always be true, you can just simplify it to use `document.getElementById("t_show").checked`
6. An `id` needs to be unique per the dom. there should only be one `t_show` per page.

Putting all that together you end up with this:

```
function showDiv(show) {
    var s = document.getElementById(show);
    if (!s) {
        return true;
    }
    s.style.display = "block";
    return true;
}

function hideDiv(hide) {
    var h = document.getElementById(hide);
    if (!h) {
        return true;
    }
    h.style.display = "none";
    return true;
}
function t_show() {
    if (document.getElementById("t_show").checked) {
        showDiv("t_settings");
    }
    else {
        hideDiv("t_settings");
    }
}
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/dJ9gf/4/).**

Comment: I don't think you should have two elements with one ID (even though they're connected by the same name). Each radio control should have it's own id, e.g. `t_show_yes` and `t_show_no` and then just check if the first one is checked or not.

Comment: @Czechnology good catch missed that one, updated the answer.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: how can i do this for multiple items

Comment: if there are multiple divs like this. Also if I wanna hide a table, or a tr, and td along with this, how do i do that.

Comment: You could use `getElementsByTagName("table")` to find all `<table/>` and than simply iterate over the node list to do `something()`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems there. Mark already pointed out most of the obvious ones. I'd add that you should always have just one element with a unique ID (even radio buttons).

Also, you don't need two JavaScript functions for the (almost) same activity.

**I'd suggest this**:

*HTML*:

```
Text show:
<input type="radio" name="t_show" value="1"  checked="checked" onchange="t_show(); update_preview();" id="t_show_yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="t_show" value="0"                    onchange="t_show(); update_preview();" id="t_show_no">No

<div id="t_settings">This content is to be shown if the show text is enabled.</div>
```

*JS*:

```
function t_show() {
    if(document.getElementById("t_show_yes").checked == true)
        setDisplay("t_settings", "");
    else
        setDisplay("t_settings", "none");
}

function setDisplay(id, value){
    var o = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!o)
        return false;
    o.style.display = value;
    return true;
}
```

Example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZptpP/

---

**EDIT** - As requested in the comments:

You could modify the t_show function to send an array of IDs to be hidden/displayed.

```
function t_show() {
    var elements = new Array("t_settings","div1","div2");

    if(document.getElementById("t_show_yes").checked == true)
        setDisplay(elements, "");
    else
        setDisplay(elements, "none");
}

function setDisplay(elements, value){
    var o;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        o = document.getElementById(elements[i]);
        if (o != undefined)
            o.style.display = value;
    }
    return true;
}
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZptpP/1

Comment: how can i do this for multiple items.

Comment: if there are multiple divs like this. Also if I wanna hide a table, or a tr, and td along with this, how do i do that.

Comment: @user658911, you could modify the `t_show` function to send an array of IDs to be hidden/displayed. See the updated answer and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZptpP/1/).

Answer (score 0):

In your show function, change...

```
 s.style.display="";
```

to

```
 s.style.display="block";
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't invoke method "t_show()" with a boolean parameter like:

t_show(true);// for input with value = 1

...

t_show(false);// for input with value = 0

and function:

```
t_show(value) {
 if(value == true){
    showDiv("t_settings");
} else {
    hideDiv("t_settings");
}
}
```

function showDiv(show){ }

function hideDiv(show){ }

so you don't need to check value...

bye